# UIScrollView - How to wrap subviews to new line when subview overflows scroll view bounds?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, word-wrap

I am creating a scrollview that will have subviews of same heights and different widths.
I wanted to know what the best way to wrap the subviews to new lines when the last subview exceeds the scroll views width bounds?

I tried detecting if the subview was outside of the scroll view bounds, then increasing the yOffset, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
if !CGRectContainsPoint(self.scrollView.frame, CGPointMake(subView.frame.origin.x+subView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.origin.y))
 {
      scrollViewOffsetY += subView.frame.height
      scrollViewOffsetX = 5
      subView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(scrollViewOffsetX, scrollViewOffsetY)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is what I did:

```
    var scrollViewOriginX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var scrollViewOriginY: CGFloat = 0.0

    for var index = 0; index < 10; index++
    {

            var subview = UIView()
            //...customize your subview here.../

            // Check if subview is out of scroll view's bounds
            if !CGRectContainsPoint(self.scrollView.bounds, CGPointMake(scrollViewOriginX + scrollViewOffsetX + subview.frame.size.width, 0))
            {
                // Increase Y Offset
                scrollViewOriginY += subview.frame.height + scrollViewOffsetY
                // Reset X Offset
                scrollViewOriginX = scrollViewOffsetX

                subview.frame.origin = CGPointMake(scrollViewOriginX, scrollViewOriginY + scrollViewOffsetY)
            }
            else
            {
                subview.frame.origin = CGPointMake(scrollViewOriginX + scrollViewOffsetX, scrollViewOriginY + scrollViewOffsetY)
            }

            self.scrollView.addSubview(subview)
            scrollViewOriginX += subview.frame.width + scrollViewOffsetX

            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.width, scrollViewOriginY+subview.frame.height+scrollViewInsetBottom)
    }
```